# Type conversion in expression may affect cardinality estimate in query plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a warning in my Execution plan that I can not get rid of. I've made an Minimal, Reproducible Example here:

```
declare @TestData Table
(
  FloatValue float null
)

insert into @TestData values
 (null), (0.1)

select 
    CONVERT(varchar, FloatValue * 100.00) + ' pct.' PctValue
from 
    @TestData
```

I've included the warning.

[image]

Comment: As an aside, you should **never** use `varchar` without specifying the length.

Comment: Unfortunately, sometimes the warnings are just, well, less than helpful. See [We Need to Talk About the Warnings in your Query Plans](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/10/we-need-to-talk-about-the-warnings-in-your-query-plans/)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I read that article, but it didn't bring me any closer to a solution

Comment: @DaleK ok changed that, but it didn't solve the problem

Comment: The "solution", unfortunately is that, having considered the warning, you're satisfied that it's not an issue in this query and you ignore it going forward. I.e. it's your behaviour that has to change, not a technical fix.

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever that was more or less my own conclusion, I just made this question to be sure.

Comment: Honestly, though, I would suggest that the above is more a task for the presentation layer; you shouldn't be formatting the data in the SQL layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `CONVERT(varchar, FloatValue * 100.00)` to `FORMAT(FloatValue * 100.00, 'N0')` in the query:

```sql
declare @TestData Table
(
  FloatValue float null
)

insert into @TestData values
 (null), (0.1)

select 
    FORMAT(FloatValue * 100.00, 'N0') + ' pct.' PctValue
from 
    @TestData
```

And it will get rid of the warning:

[image: The warning 'Type conversion in expression may affect cardinality estimate in query plan' is now gone from the message box]

Comment: The warning is benign, the format however could be a costly performance penalty to pay!

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server is sometimes a little over cautious with its warnings.

You can encounter various warnings in the execution plan that, after review, prove to be irrelevant; for example you may sometimes see a warning about an excessive memory grant, even though the grant is literally the *minimum* configured amount possible per query.

As this is not a column involved with filtering or joining decision making you can safely disregard it.